# "List you favorite" Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to post a 'community question' that will be titled something like "What is your favorite X"? (where X is some family of mathematical objects - I don't want to be very specific right now although I have a specific example in mind).

It is not a question I've seen before (I searched), it certainly interests me and I think the community can benefit from it. But I am not sure what is the policy regarding those kind of questions.

1. Is it OK to post questions like this? Is there some rule of thumb for that?
2. As there's no correct answer for this kind of question, what should I do?

Comment: [From the FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): *Avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”* I'd encourage you to read the rest of the FAQ too, in case there is something else that you missed.

Comment: (At the time of my comment) 6 downvotes and 0 upvotes -- I though that downvotes on meta expressed disagreement, and I don't see how one can disagree with a question. If you think that meta answers this question, it doesn't; there is, for example, a question that starts with "What is your favorite" which has 34 upvotes and 0 downvotes. Especially with the recent outburst of meta opinions suggesting that community's will is to be followed, and not some abstract set of rules written on some FAQ/Blog, I would say this is a perfectly valid question even if one has read the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry, the 'meta' in "If you think that meta answers" should be 'FAQ'. I'm posting this instead of editing because I the time period for editing has passed.

Comment: @Q__ We all know what is the most upvoted question on this site, but I don't take it as evidence that users should be posting more pictures of Batman.

Comment: The downvotes are most likely from users that think that you shouldn't ask such questions. Like you said, downvotes on meta represent also disagreement.

Comment: Several questions in a similar spirit have already been posted: [Your favourite application of the Baire category theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165696/your-favourite-application-of-the-baire-category-theorem/),
[What is your favorite application of the Pigeonhole Principle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62565/what-is-your-favorite-application-of-the-pigeonhole-principle),
[What are your favorite integration tricks?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162154/what-are-your-favorite-integration-tricks).

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons to close such a post (almost immediately) is this: When you click the "close" button on a question you see

> > **not constructive**
> >
> > As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references or specific expertise; but this question will likely solicit debate,arguments, polling, or extended discussion. "

Based on this your question will most likely be closed immediately (I will certainly vote to close).